# mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I'm trying to run mongodb server :

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

this gives me no error, but when I try to check the status, I get error saying :

```
mua@mua  ~  sudo systemctl status mongod               ✔  2916  14:07:16 

● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-04-27 14:07:16 +06; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 13625 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exite
 Main PID: 13625 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua mongod[13625]: {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-27T08:07:16.650Z"},"
এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exit
এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
lines 1-11/11 (END)...skipping...
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-04-27 14:07:16 +06; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 13625 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13625 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua mongod[13625]: {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-27T08:07:16.650Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Err
এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
এপ্রিল 27 14:07:16 mua systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
~
```

Here is some details :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.5",
    "gitVersion": "ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu1804",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solving this problem ?

Here is the service

```
 mua@mua  /lib/systemd/system  cat mongod.service   127 ↵  3002  13:28:11 
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Have a look at your mongo log file, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit there is no `mongodb` or any directory starting or containing `m` in `/var/log/`

Comment: logfile is defined in `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think there is a big big problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1oFd.png

Comment: Solution should be obvious...

Answer (score 0):

Looks familiar... If you check your mongod.service file (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service), there should be line what tells where mongod.pid file is located (PIDFile=/tmp/mongod.pid). That same file (with path) should be found from your /etc/mongod.conf file.

```
processManagement:
  pidFilePath: /tmp/mongod.pid
```

Problem is that, after 5 second when you have said 'sudo systemctl start mongod.service', system will check "is there mongod.pid" and because it cannot find it, it will KILL that running mongod-process.

Comment: I've added the whole service, will you please check ?
there is no sign of temp regarding process-management